# Audio Onload Percentage indicatior

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

before website i have black screen with Audio load percent, for all the audio that needs to be loaded but it doesnt work. The audioloadpercent text is either blank or Zero

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Audio Loaded</td><td>Images Loaded</td></tr>
    <tr><td><span id="audioLoadPercent"></span>%</td><td><span id="imagesLoadPercent"></span>%</td></tr>
</table>
<audio id="jungle" nocontrols src="music/jungle.mp3" type="audio/mp3" preload="auto" onload="audioLoaded();"></audio>
<audio id="swipe" nocontrols src="sounds/swipe.mp3" type="audio/mp3" preload="auto" onload="audioLoaded();"></audio>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var audioLoadedPercent=0;
var imagesLoadedPercent=0;
function audioLoaded(){
    audioLoadedPercent=audioLoadedPercent+Math.round(Math.random()*50)
    document.getElementById("audioLoadPercent").innerHTML=audioLoadedPercent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use oncanplaythrough or onloadeddata instead of onload for the audio tags